# MYSQL Query TAKING user's participation place with quantity of all other participants

Tags: mysql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I am making a website where users add the place where they have visited.

There is 4 main tables

```
users (user_id,name )
places (place_id,type_id,place_name, city_id)
user_place (user_id,place_id, date )
city(city_id,city_name)
```

Now I need to take with one query all the places which are type of 2 `(where type=2)` where the given users participate `(user_id=43 lets say)` with the name of the place, name of the city and the quantity of ALL OTHER  users  which are also participating in the same place... 
Yesterday with one book about mysql I  came to such thing

```
    SELECT *
    FROM `user_place` , `places`,(SELECT count(user_id) 
 from user_places
 WHERE user_place.place_id = places.place_id) as count
    WHERE user_place.place_id = places.place_id
    AND user_place.user_id =53
```

But its giving error:Unknown column 'places.place_id' in 'where clause' 
And still no Idea how can I also attach smartly the place name and city name to the result...
Please help if you can...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.place_id, p.place_name, c.city, placeCount.Cnt
FROM places p
INNER JOIN user_place up ON p.place_id = up.place_id
INNER JOIN fa_user u ON up.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN city c ON p.city_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT place_id, COUNT( DISTINCT user_id ) Cnt
FROM user_place
WHERE user_id <>53
GROUP BY place_id
)placeCount ON p.place_id = placeCount.place_id
WHERE up.user_id =53
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look at something like this

```
SELECT  u.user_id,
        u.NAME,
        p.place_id,
        p.place_name,
        c.city_id,
        c.city_name,
        placeCount.Cnt
FROM    places p INNER JOIN
        user_place up ON p.place_id = up.place_id INNER JOIN
        users u ON up.user_id = u.user_id INNER JOIN
        city c ON p.city_id = c.city_id LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  place_id,
                    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) Cnt
            FROM    user_place
            WHERE   user_id <> 43
            GROUP BY place_id
        ) placeCount ON p.place_id = placeCount.place_id
WHERE   p.type_id = 2
AND     up.user_id = 43
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[USER_ID],
        u.NAME,
        p.place_id,
        p.place_name,
       ' at line 1 

I get this when I enter your given QUery...